# Is there a list of words coined by authors such as Shakespeare?

Tags: etymology

There are some lists of words coined by specific authors, but what I'd like to find, if it exists, is a meta-list of words coined by canonical authors (Shakespeare, Milton, etc). At the very least, is there a list (preferably online somewhere) of Milton's coinages?

Comment: I think in many cases it's difficult to tell whether an author coined a word or was the first to write it down.

Comment: As snailboat implies, this is largely unanswerable. There aren't *that* many pre-Elizabethan texts, so the fact that our earliest citation for some term is from Shakespeare, Milton, Spencer or whoever doesn't necessarily tell us much about whether the specific writer "coined" any given usage. But [here are over 400 words](http://shakespeare-w.com/english/shakespeare/words.html) where the earliest citation in OED is from Shakespeare, so that's a start.

Comment: According to [the Guardian](http://www.theguardian.com/uk/2008/jan/28/britishidentity.johncrace), Milton may be responsible for introducing up to 630 new words. [Some are here](http://sjhoward.co.uk/archive/2012/01/12/miltons-neologisms) and [some are here](http://herodotuswept.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/words-invented-by-john-milton/).

Comment: Many words beginning *un-*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a difference between coining (usually we'll never know who coined a word) and who was the first person we currently know of who wrote it down. See also this *Boston Globe* article: "[Coined by Shakespeare? Think again. New research indicates he didn’t make up all those words—he just used them better.](http://www.bostonglobe.com/ideas/2013/08/17/coined-shakespeare-think-again/tWFE6b8qTD5gnybL5fOn8H/story.html)"

However, there are lists of first recorded words by popular authors.

The *Oxford English Dictionary* requires a subscription (though your local library may subscribe) and has a [list of their top 1,000 sources](http://www.oed.com/sources). Clicking each source allows you to see their quotations: their top 10 most quoted texts; quotations: first in entry; quotations: first in sense; and quotations: other.

- Shakespeare is the 2nd most frequently quoted source in the OED, with a total of 33,149 quotations (about 1.06% of all OED quotations). 1,594 are the first evidence of a word and 8,018 are first evidence of a particular meaning.
- Milton is the 7th most frequently quoted source in the OED, with a total of 12,429 quotations (about 0.4% of all OED quotations). 595 are the first evidence of a word and 2,103 are first evidence of a particular meaning.

Comment: Thank you, Hugo. I'm a frequent user of the OED, but wasn't aware of this facility.